# RewriteEngine for different scenarios

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm a bit struggling with the `RewriteEngine` using with a Linux machine.

Needed is to have 4 scenarios, 2 are working fine, 2 not (for sure because I do any kind of misconfiguration).

My goals:

1. Works

Only valid for 192.168.1.**10x** IPs
`http://192.168.1.2:81/api?key=value` -> `http://192.168.1.3:8080/api?key=value`

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =81
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.10[0-9]$
RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.1.3:8080/api
```

---

2. Works

Only valid for 192.168.1.**15x** IPs
`http://192.168.1.2:81/api?key=value` -> `http://192.168.1.4:8080/api?key=value`

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =81
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.15[0-9]$
RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.1.4:8080/api
```

---

3. Does not work

Only valid for 192.168.1.**10x** IPs
`http://192.168.1.2:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` -> `http://192.168.1.3:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json`

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.10[0-9]$
RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.1.3:80
```

Going to `http://192.168.1.2:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` then I get redirected to
`http://192.168.1.3:80` but not to
`http://192.168.1.3:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json`

---

4. Does not work

Only valid for 192.168.1.**15x** IPs
`http://192.168.1.2:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` -> `http://192.168.1.4:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json`

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.15[0-9]$
RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.1.4:80
```

Going to `http://192.168.1.2:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` then I get redirected to
`http://192.168.1.3:80` but not to
`http://192.168.1.3:80/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json`

Comment: For #3 and #4 you give only a static example of `/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` (which should redirect to the same). But should this really be for any URL, or literally just that one static URL?

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Does not work
>
>    ```
>    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
>    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.10[0-9]$
>    RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.1.3:80
>    ```

(The same applies to both #3 and #4.)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^` is successful for every URL-path, but you are only redirecting to `http://192.168.1.3:80` - you need to append the original URL-path.

*Aside:* Note that you are also missing the `R` and `L` flags from all the rules. Without which this *defaults* to a 302 (temporary) redirect, but you should be explicit. You need the `L` flag to prevent the directives that follow from being (unnecessarily) processed.

It's not clear from your example whether you only want to target `/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` or whether that is intended to be "general speak" for *any* URL?

If it's just that one static URL then modify the `RewriteRule` like so:

```
:
RewriteRule ^/?my/fancy/folder/myFile\.json$ http://192.168.1.3:80%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable (the value of which is accessed using the syntax `%{REQUEST_URI}`) contains the requested URL-path (including the slash prefix). This saves repeating/hardcoding the URL-path `/my/fancy/folder/myFile.json` in the *substitution* string.

If, however, this is intended to work for *any* URL then modify the `RewriteRule` accordingly. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^ http://192.168.1.3:80%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

---

#### Rules #1 and #2 that "work"

The reason why #1 and #2 "work" is because the *query string* part of the URL (ie. `key=value`) - which is not part of the URL-path - is passed through to the *substitution* string by default.

However, these two rules are not specifically targeting `/api` only (as the description seems to imply), they redirect `/<anything>` to `/api` (a many-to-one redirect) - which is probably not the intention. (?)

If you only want to target `/api` then you need to specify this URL-path in the rule. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?api$ http://192.168.1.3:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```